# How to get post data on window.load in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to get the Form's post data on call of this function

```
$(window).load(function()
```

Used the following to get the value but it does nothing.

```
$('#id_state').val();
```

Comment: I think you can use $_POST in javascript during page load. Such as <script type="text/javascript">var id_state = "$_POST['id_state']"</script>

Comment: Any error in browser console?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, this is what you need:

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        var id_state=<?php if(isset($_POST["id_state"]){echo $_POST["id_state"];}else{ echo 0;}?>;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to submit form using ajax

below just example not a perfect answer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="formoid" action="studentFormInsert.php" title="" method="post">
            <div>
                <label class="title">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" >
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="title">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" >
           </div>
           <div>
               <input type="submit" id="submitButton"  name="submitButton" value="Submit">
           </div>
       </form>
       <script type='text/javascript'>
           /* attach a submit handler to the form */
           $("#formoid").submit(function(event) {

              /* stop form from submitting normally */
              event.preventDefault();

              /* get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element */
              var $form = $( this ),
              url = $form.attr( 'action' );

              /* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
              var posting = $.post( url, { name: $('#name').val(), name2: $('#name2').val() } );

              /* Alerts the results */
              posting.done(function( data ) {
                  alert('success');
              });
          });
      </script>
</body>
```